# Why do we assume all controls are exogenous in an instrumental variable analysis?

Tags: instrumental-variables

I have seen two instructions for estimating the first-stage OLS for IV:

1. Regress the endogenous variable (predictor of interest) on the instrument and controls that will be used in the second-stage
2. Regress the endogenous variable on the instrument and all exogenous variables that will be used in the second stage

These two rules imply that all controls in the second-stage are assumed to be exogenous. Why? If I have a contorl that is endogenous, do I still include it in the first-stage?

Answer (score 0):

In 2SLS you divide predictors into exogenous (instruments) $Z$ and endogenous variables $X$: $Y=X\beta_X+Z\beta_Z$. In 1st stage you regress $X= Z\beta_{IV}+u$, then obtain estimators $\hat X=Z\beta_{IV}$. In the second stage you plug these into main equation: $Y=\hat X\beta_X+Z\beta_Z+\varepsilon=Z(\beta_{IV}\beta_X+\beta_Z)+\varepsilon$

Once you solve the equation, your coefficients $\hat\beta_X$ are for the endogenous variable.